# Dynamic homepage not working with Change Notifier Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have authProvider which has isLoggedIn property.

The widget setup is as

```
Consumer<AuthProvider>(
          builder: (ctx, authProvider, _) {
            Widget initialScreen = const OnBoardingScreen1();
            if (authProvider.isLoggedIn) {
              initialScreen = const HomeScreen();
            }
            log(authProvider.isLoggedIn.toString());
            return MaterialApp(
              title: 'Flutter App',
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
              home: initialScreen,
              onGenerateRoute: (settings) => RouteGenerator.getRoute(settings),
            );
          },
        )
```

When the app is initially launched then it works as expected i.e. Home Page is dynamic according to isLoggedIn state.

But when the isLoggedIn is updated with a login event then it doesnot switch to the HomeScreen widget although the log function logs true value.

How to resolve this? Or is manually pushing to HomeScreen route is the only option here?

Comment: Do you call `notifyListeners` from `AuthProvider` when a log in event occurs?

Comment: Yes. I have called it. That's why consumer is reloaded and the log function logs true but screen is not navigated